# I'm trying to use the rufus scheduling gem from the controller to pull the lowest price from an api every min

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, model-view-controller, scheduler

this is in my initializer which works perfectly for pulling all lowest prices and avg price every 5, 10, 20, etc. seconds

```
    unless defined?(Rails::Console) || File.split($0).last == 'rake'
 s = Rufus::Scheduler.singleton
 s.every '10m' do
   Rails.logger.info "hello, it's {Time.now}"
   Rails.logger.flush
   Bid.all.each do |bid|
     id = bid.event_id
    @events = Unirest.get("https://api.seatgeek.com/2/events/#{id}?&client_id=NjQwNTEzMXwxNDgxNDkxODI1").body
    if @events["stats"]
      @low = @events["stats"]["lowest_price"] || 0
      @avg = @events["stats"]["average_price"] || 0
      BuyNowBid.create(bid_id: bid.id, lowest_price: @low , average_price: @avg)
    end
  end 
end
end
```

But when i try to create a bid from the controller and then try pull the lowest and average price from the api it doesn't work been sitting been working on this for a few hours now any tips would be much appreciated.

```
    def create 
#@bid?
#seatgeek id 
@bidd = Bid.new(event_id: params[:event_id], user_id: session[:user_id], bid: params[:bid], lowest_price: params[:lowest_price])    
if session[:user_id] == current_user.id
  @bidd.save
  @events = Unirest.get("https://api.seatgeek.com/2/events/#{@bidd.event_id}?&client_id=NjQwNTEzMXwxNDgxNDkxODI1").body
  if @events["stats"]
    @low = @events["stats"]["lowest_price"] || 0
    @avg = @events["stats"]["average_price"] || 0
    BuyNowBid.create(bid_id: @bidd.id, lowest_price: @low , average_price: @avg)
  end

  Rufus::Scheduler.singleton.every '10s' do
    @events = Unirest.get("https://api.seatgeek.com/2/events/#{@bidd.event_id}?&client_id=NjQwNTEzMXwxNDgxNDkxODI1").body
    if @events["stats"]
      @low = @events["stats"]["lowest_price"] || 0
      @avg = @events["stats"]["average_price"] || 0
      BuyNowBid.create(bid_id: @bidd.id, lowest_price: @low , average_price: @avg)
    end
  end
  flash[:success] = "bid created."
  redirect_to "/users/#{current_user.id}"
else
  flash[:warning] = 'please sign in'
  redirect_to '/login'
end
end
```

Comment: maybe instead create an update method in my model?

Comment: what error do you get..?

Comment: thats the thing i dont get an error its just not running the scheduler but when I do it from the initializer it does

Comment: i may try to run it from the bid model and call it on the show page and I'm not sure if update or create would work better? because as you can see above I'm creating a BuyNowBid before I run rufus so i was think it may work better using the update action after

Comment: I'm trying to save the lowest price from an api so i can monitor it over time  as well as to be notified if a bid matches the lowest price

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a way to do by reading more of the rufus documentation and tinkering with it for a while.  I was able to create a method that accessed the rufus scheduler in my initializer.

```
    def restart_jobs
puts 'Stopping rufus'
Rufus::Scheduler.singleton.jobs(:tag => 'main_process').each do |job|
 Rufus::Scheduler.singleton.unschedule(job)
end
puts 'Starting rufus'
load "#{Rails.root}/config/initializers/scheduler.rb"
```

end
  end
and im calling that restart jobs method after a bid is created so that the bid a user just created gets added to the scheduler when it starts back up

```
    def create 
@bidd = Bid.new(event_id: params[:event_id], user_id: session[:user_id], bid: params[:bid], lowest_price: params[:lowest_price])    
if session[:user_id] == current_user.id
  @bidd.save
  send_message("+13125501444", "test")
  restart_jobs
  flash[:success] = "bid created."
  redirect_to "/users/#{current_user.id}"
else
  flash[:warning] = 'please sign in'
  redirect_to '/login'
end
end
```

the only part i changed in the scheduler in the intializer is adding the hash

```
    :tag => 'main_process'
```

and here it is in the scheduler

```
    unless defined?(Rails::Console) || File.split($0).last == 'rake'
 s = Rufus::Scheduler.singleton
 s.every '1m', :tag => 'main_process' do
   Rails.logger.info "hello, it's #{Time.now}"
   Rails.logger.flush
```